# Ajax doesn't work by retrieving big file from database

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

By retrieving file more than 0.5MB from SQL database ajax falls into error every time, what am I doing wrong here?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

loadFileData();


  });

  function loadFileData() {

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/File/FileIndex",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var trow = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.id);
            var trowa = $('<tr/>');
            var trowb = $('<tr/>').data("id", val.id);
            trow.append('<td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="FileDownload">' + escape(val.Name)  +'</a></td>');
            trowa.append('<td><input type="file" id="FileUpload" /></form></td>');
            trowb.append('<td><input type="button" class="btnUpload" value="Upload File" /><input type="button" id="btnClear" value="Clear" /></td>');

            tab.append(trow);
            tab.append(trowa);
            tab.append(trowb);

        });
        $("#showFiles").html(tab);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Failed! Please try again." + error);
    }
});
var tab = $('<table style="width:100px" border=1 class=MyTable></table>');
   }
```

my controller:

```
//GET: File
    public JsonResult FileIndex()
    {

        List<tblFile> fileList = new List<tblFile>();
        using (FileDBEntities db = new FileDBEntities())
        {
            fileList = db.tblFiles.ToList();
        }

        return new JsonResult { Data = fileList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
    }
```

with small files it works perfectley, but why it falls down by retriving file more than 0,5MB?
message, what I'm reciving:

```
function(){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?
(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: Is this only happening in production or can you reproduce it in a development environment? If you can reproduce it in a development environment, you can use a debugger to see the error (and possibly other useful information). If you haven't yet learned how to use a debugger, that should be your next task.

Comment: yeah, should i, but i dont understand why does it works with small files?

Comment: as i can see in console there are following errors:
1. GET https://localhost:44395/resources/demos/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
2. bootstrap.js:15 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4
3.GET https://localhost:44395/File/FileIndex 500

Comment: Additional, what i cn see it something with serialization, maxJSONLength

Comment: if its something on server site, why does it works then with little files?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should:

Your Controller: you should return with binary || file Stream

```
//GET: File
public JsonResult FileIndex()
{

    List<byte> fileList = new List<byte>();
    using (FileDBEntities db = new FileDBEntities())
    {
        fileList = db.tblFiles.ToList();
        
        foreach(var itemFile in fileList) {
           fileList.add(File.ReadAllBytes(itemFile));
        }
    }
    return new JsonResult { Data = fileList, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Comment: there are 2 errors:

"File" is not valid in current contest and can not implicity convert type

Comment: first error belongs to fileList = db.tblFiles.ToList();
second one to fileList.add(File.ReadAllBytes(itemFile));